# Opencart address page pagination

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination, opencart

I'm trying to break down opencart address list to 20 per page, but it still shows all list on page 1 and page 2. Please take a look at the codes, I must do something wrong.

The pagination looks fine

> 1 2 > >|
>   Showing 1 to 20 of 31 (2 Pages)

The codes on controller account `address.php` page within `protected function getList()` (I tried `public function index()` as well).

```
if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
     $page = $this->request->get['page'];
  } else {
     $page = 1;
  }      

  $data = array(              
     'start' => ($page - 1) * 20,
     'limit' => 20
  );

  $address_total = $this->model_account_address->getTotalAddresses($data);
  $results = $this->model_account_address->getAddresses();

  $pagination = new Pagination();
  $pagination->total = $address_total;
  $pagination->page = $page;
  $pagination->limit = 20; 
  $pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');
  $pagination->url = $this->url->link('account/address', 'page={page}', 'SSL');

  $this->data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();
```

and codes on model account `address.php`

```
public function getDetails($data = array()) {
  $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "address` WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");

  if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
     if ($data['start'] < 0) {
        $data['start'] = 0;
     }         

     if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
        $data['limit'] = 20;
     }   

     $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
  }

  $query = $this->db->query($sql);

  $details = $query->rows;

return $details;
}
```

This is on view `address_list.tpl`

```
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your model. You run the query before you fill in the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, change your model to this:

```
public function getDetails($data = array()) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . DB_PREFIX . 'address` WHERE customer_id = ' . (int)$this->customer->getId();

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= ' LIMIT ' . (int)$data['start'] . ',' . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

This should do it.

Actually after your first call to `$sql = $this->db->query("...");` (first line in your model's method) the `$sql` variable does not contain the SQL query but the *OpenCart DB resource object* containing properties `row` (first row), `rows` (all the retrieved rows) and `num_rows` (amount of retrieved rows). Therefore your second call `$query = $this->db->query($sql);` should give you an error - if it is not displayed maybe you have hidden the PHP errors. Check your PHP error log (or OpenCart's error log) to find out.

**EDIT**:

Then in Your controller you have this logical error: you are setting the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` for the `getTotalAddresses($data)` which should count **ALL** of the addresses - but this will always return the number **`20`**. On the other hand, the method that should get those parameteres, does not get them: `getAddresses();`

So fix your controller to do this:

```
$address_total = $this->model_account_address->getTotalAddresses();
// no $data here as we want all the addresses to be counted ----^^
$results = $this->model_account_address->getAddresses($data);
// we pass $data here so the LIMIT is applied --------^^^^^
```

And one more thing: in your controller you call **`getAddresses`** but in your model **`getDetails`** is defined... Are you sure you do not want to rename `getDetails` to **`getAddresses`**?

Comment: I accepted your answer, there must have more mistakes somewhere else because the lists still haven't broken down.

Comment: Oh, now I realized them :-). Check my edited answer!